# Binding to nested control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have used a custom data grid control that adds a TextBox to the column headers for filtering. Unfortunately, i have faced a problem when i tried to bind Visiblilty property of DataGridRow to Text property of TextBox (called filterTextBox); see the bellow code. The object received in the converter method "SearchColumnToVisibilityConverter" has the value "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue".

```html
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpuDataGrid}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
                            <TextBox Width="200" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtFullTextSearch" 
                                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding EnableFullTextSearch, 
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                            <DataGrid x:Name="simpuGrid" 
                                      ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" CanUserAddRows="{TemplateBinding CanUserAddRows}"
                                      CanUserDeleteRows="{TemplateBinding CanUserDeleteRows}" 
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="{TemplateBinding AutoGenerateColumns}">
                                <DataGrid.Resources>

                                    <!--Custom Column Header template to show extra elements in the header-->
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                                    <!--Let's keep the top section grid to contain the DataGridHeaderBorder, and left+right thumbs.-->
                                                    <Grid x:Name="fullHeader" Background="{StaticResource normalBrushBack}">

                                                        <!--Here is the theme based DataGridHeaderBorder. I've used Aero here.-->
                                                        <aero:DataGridHeaderBorder x:Name='HeaderBorder' SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  Background="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" SeparatorBrush="#FFC9CACA">
                                                            <!--We will put 3 elements inside the border: Content of header, a drop down button, and a sort order indicator.-->
                                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                    <!--For ContentPresenter-->
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                                    <!--For drop down button-->
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <!--For ContentPresenter-->
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                                    <!--For sort order indicator-->
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12" />
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <!--Content of the header.-->
                                                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" >
                                                                    <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerConverter}">
                                                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                                                <Binding ElementName="filterTextBox" Path="Text" />
                                                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Content" />
                                                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                    </ContentPresenter.Content>
                                                                </ContentPresenter>
                                                                <!--A textbox filter-->
                                                                <TextBox x:Name="filterTextBox" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                                                <!--A sort order arrow icon.-->
                                                                <Path x:Name="SortArrow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="8" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Visibility="Visible" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Uniform"  Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z" />
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </aero:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                                            <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </Trigger>

                                                        <Trigger Property='IsMouseOver' SourceName="fullHeader" Value='True'>
                                                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.20000"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                     To='1.0' />
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.20000"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                                     To='0' />
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                    <!--End of custom DataGridColumnHeader template-->
                                </DataGrid.Resources>
                                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchColumnToVisibilityConverter}">
                                                    <Binding ElementName="filterTextBox" Path="Text"/>
                                                    <Binding BindsDirectlyToSource="True"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </StackPanel>                        
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

I hope someone could help me!

Thanks

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to go through, it would be simpler to identify the problem if only the code needed to recreate the issue were included. It may also be useful to see the code for SearchColumnToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: I am afraid you can't refer to a control defined in a `ControlTemplate` in another `Style`.